# How do i make a request to a json api and get a field from it?

Tags: json, node.js, express, request

```
const express = require('express');
const req = require('request')

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

var server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on ' + port);
});

app.route('/rap').get((request, result) => {
    if(!request.query.u) { result.send("Please provide a user!"); return 0}
    req("https://rbx.rocks/apis/user_items?u="+request.query.u, function(error, response, body) {
        var jsonbody = JSON.parse(body)
        result.send(jsonbody.stats.RAP)
    })
});
```

The code above tells me that jsonbody.stats doesn't exist but when I print jsonbody it clearly shows that stats does exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API looks to be *very* strange. It appears to return JSON containing a single string. That string is in turn a JSON object. So you'll need to first parse the body and then parse the string it contains.

Give this a try:

```
var jsonbody = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(body));
result.send(jsonbody.stats.RAP);
```

Comment: It would sometimes give me errors saying that its already an object so i did this...

```if (typeof jsonbody != 'object') { jsonbody = JSON.parse(jsonbody) }```